# Jquery 1.10.2 $.each function not working

Tags: jquery

Ok, first let me describe my HTML.

I have a select list name and ID as upload_Gcat that has three options. I then have a select list name and ID as upload_album. What I want is as upload_Gcat is changed upload_album changes its options according to what was selected. I have gotten my query to work as far as removing the old. But when it reaches my $.each function it does not work.

I have tried various different code lines inside the $.each function, even tried the bad debug way of alerts, no alert showed up while inside of $.each.

```
var new_options = new Array();
new_options["album1"] = "album1";
new_options["album2"] = "album2";
new_options["album3"] = "album3";

var select = $('upload_album');
if(select.prop){
    var options = select.prop('options');
}
else{
    var options = select.attr('options');
}

$('option', select).remove();

$.each(new_options, function(key, value) {
    options[options.length] = new Option(value, value);
});
```

Comment: Arrays are not associative in JS, use object instead: `var new_options = {};`

Comment: _"Ok, first let me describe my html"_ - A picture is worth a thousand words. Or, in this case, why don't you show the markup for the elements in question?

Comment: Also, `$.each` has an iterator signature of `function(index, object)`.

Comment: [`jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this (Use an `object` instead of `array`, JavaScript doesn't support associative array)

```
var new_options = {}; // an empty object
new_options["album1"] = "album1";
new_options["album2"] = "album2";
new_options["album3"] = "album3";

var select = $('#upload_album').empty();
$.each(new_options, function(key, value) {
    var newOption = $('<option/>', {'value':key, 'text':value});
    select.append(newOption);
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bhJ7w/1/) Also, check [**Working with objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on MDN.